# Using IN operator in DynamoDB from Boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB and trying to query a table based off the presence of a list of certain values for a field.

I have a field `doc_id`, which is also a secondary index, and I'd like to return all results where `doc_id` is contained in a list of values.

I'm trying something like this:

```
response = table.query(
IndexName='doc_id-index',
FilterExpression=In(['27242226'])
)
```

But clearly that is not correct.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like`SELECT
  id
FROM
  tbl1
WHERE
  id IN (1, 2, 6, 3, 8)`

Comment: Yes, exactly.  ```Select * from table where doc_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)```

Answer (score 0):

with Query operation

> A FilterExpression does not allow key attributes. You cannot define a filter expression based on a partition key or a sort key.

So, Your `doc_id` field is the partition key of the `doc_id-index` and cannot be used in FilterExpression.

> **Note**
>   A FilterExpression is applied after the items have already been read; the process of filtering does not consume any additional read capacity units.

I'm assuming you have another field like `userId`, just to show how to implement IN operation.(Query)

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'tbl',
    IndexName: 'doc_id-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'doc_id= :doc_id', 
    FilterExpression: 'userId IN (:userId1,:userId2)',//you can add more userId here

    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ':doc_id':100,
         ':userId1':11,
         ':userId2':12
                                 }

};
```

If you have more userId you should pass to FilterExpression dynamically.

but in your case, you can use Scan operation

```
var params = {
    TableName : "tbl",
    FilterExpression : "doc_id IN (:doc_id1, :doc_id2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
                   ":doc_id1" :100,
                   ":doc_id2" :101
                                 }
                    };
```

and even pass to FilterExpression dynamically like below

```
var documentsId = ["100", "101","200",...];
var documentsObj = {};
var index = 0;
documentsId.forEach((value)=> {
    index++;
    var documentKey = ":doc_id"+index;
    documentsObj[documentKey.toString()] = value;
});

var params = {
    TableName: 'job',
    FilterExpression: 'doc_id IN ('+Object.keys(documentsObj).toString()+')',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: documentsObj,
};
```

**Note**:be careful while using Scan operation, less efficient than Query.

Comment: Not only is it less efficient, it is WAY more expensive cost wise. In addition, if someone is doing a scan for a primary or secondary access pattern, they really need to reevaluate their data model to tune it to their access patterns instead. Now if it is an access pattern that is only done every so often, it is possible the cost of the scan is cheaper than maintaining a secondary index.