# How do I scan a table filtering for multiple values using nodejs and dynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the following query:

```
params2 = {
            TableName: "tableName",
            ProjectionExpression: "C1, C33, C34, C2, C3",
            FilterExpression: "#field1 = :customer and #field2 = :dominios",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#field2": "C2"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":dominios": "demo.es"
            }
};
```

This works well.
But now I need to check for several dominios. It means that ":dominios" can be a list with multiple values:

```
:dominios = ["demo1.es", "demo2.es"..]
```

How can implement this?

In a regular SQL expression will be something like:

```
Where dominio = "demo1.es" OR dominio = "demo2.es" .....
or 
Where dominio IN ("demo1.es", "demo2.es",...)
```

I am using Node Js and DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see the example code below:

```
var params = {
     TableName: "tableName",
     ProjectionExpression: "C1, C33, C34, C2, C3",
     FilterExpression : "#field2 IN (:dominio1 , :dominio2,:dominio3)",
     ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#field2": "C2"
            },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
                   ":dominio1" :"demo3",
                   ":dominio2" :"demo2",
                   ":dominio2" :"demo3"
                                 }
                    };
```

for more items you can pass dynamically.[look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753529/4855817)